# Compile Bootstrap 2 with Simpless

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

Is there a way to compile [Boostrap 2](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) with [Simpless](http://wearekiss.com/simpless)?

More about the issue: https://github.com/Paratron/SimpLESS/issues/33

Anybody solved this?

**UPDATE**

***PROBLEM SOLVED!***

I don't delete the question, because maybe it can be useful for others.

To solve the problem change the less.js inside of the Simpless app, with this:
https://github.com/Costo/SimpLESS/edit/patch-1/Resources/js/less.js

Comment: You should add your solution as an answer and accept it.

Comment: I can't believe that this question was closed as "too localized". This applies to at least hundreds, if not many thousands of people!

Comment: Yeh, I think it's going to help many too!

Comment: Maybe not.  The link to the js file is dead.